# Codeigniter - Htaccess : How to change a controller name

Tags: codeigniter, routes, controllers

This is my first question here, so Hi all! ^^

I created a website with codeigniter framework and I have inserted a module for multilanguage. The url looks like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/en/controller/function
```

The problem came when the client wanted to send a newsletter to all its customers in another language, but do not want to send the url with the controler with the name in english, because  the newsletter is for spanish users.So:

```
URL is going to be send:
http://www.mywebsite.com/es/thecontroller
```

```
URL the client wants to be send ("elcontrolador" is "thecontroler" in spanish):
http://www.mywebsite.com/es/elcontrolador
```

I dont want to create another controler named "elcontorlador" only to show the same page as "thecontroler", because we don't want duplicate content for SEO purposes.

So, i want via .htaccess, a rule that when i type

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/es/elcontrolador
```

in the URL, mywebpage shows the info of

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/es/thecontroler
```

but with the URL

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/es/elcontrolador
```

(the controler "elcontrolador" doesnt exist).

So, is there any way to do this with the htaccess? I've tried it myself but I failed miserably i come here desperate, because I run out of time to deliver it and can not find a viable solution. I'll have to create the extra controller?

Need help D:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the route config file instead to achieve this ?

```
$route['es/elcontrolador'] = 'es/thecontroler';
```

I don't know how you handle your multilangage, but you've got the idea.